# Push an array within an array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I created a function called "keyword_query()" which gets a single string and runs a query with this variable on an API - then the API returns an array (which is defined global so it's changed outside the function too).

The second function "keyword_query_array()" should run the "keyword_query()" more than once, and push to a new array (which is global too) and get an array of several arrays. This function gets a variable of an array of keywords. The function gets the array and navigates through the array without any problem.

Please notice the comments in the code:

```
<?php

// Runs the query "Research Key" on a keyword and get App ids, names, ect'. 
function keyword_query($keyword){

    global $research_key_array, $keyword;

    // Add the keyword to the "Research Key" query: 
    $research_key_query = "https://example.com/api/banana/ajax/kaka?term=$keyword&country=US&auth_token=666";

    // Create a stream for Json. That's how the code knows what to expect to get. 
    $context_opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => "GET",
            'header' => "Accepts: application/json\r\n"
        )
    ); 
    $context = stream_context_create($context_opts); 

    // Get the Json
    $research_key_json = file_get_contents($research_key_query, false, $context); 

    // Turn Json to a PHP array
    $research_key_array = json_decode($research_key_json, true);
    //var_dump($research_key_array);
    //print_r($research_key_array);

    return $research_key_array;
}


// Runs the keyword_query() function on an array of keywords.
function keyword_query_array($keyword_array){

    global $array_of_key_queries;

    // Get the last array cell
    $last_array_cell = count($keyword_array);

    // Navigate through the array
    for ($i=0; $i<=$last_array_cell ; $i++) { 

        //echo $keyword_array[$i]; ****works!

        // Error here: Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\PHPExcel\api_fun.php on line 51
        array_push( $array_of_key_queries, keyword_query($keyword_array[$i]) );

    }

    var_dump($array_of_key_queries);

}
```

But when I get to this line: 
`array_push( $array_of_key_queries, keyword_query($keyword_array[$i]) );` I get an error of:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\PHPExcel\api_fun.php on line 51

with this var_dump:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'keyword' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'keyword' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'keyword' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'keyword' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

What is the right way to push an array within an array like this case?

Comment: try changing your for loop to this `for ($i=0; $i<$last_array_cell ; $i++)`

Comment: check before accessing the array element by using key, please check whether it is available or not like isset($keyword_array[$i]). It may help to remove the notice error. another method to concatenate the array is $array1+$array2. this also will work. please let me know

Comment: @Adelphia I don't get the error msg anymore now (what was the problem? :O)

Comment: AND - I still get an array of empty arrays :S

Comment: The problem was the equals sign. It was looping all indexes then looping one extra time for the equals sign. Now you need to check the `keyword_query()` function since it's returning an empty array.

Comment: I run this in the main .php file: 

`$keyword = "banana";
var_dump( keyword_query($keyword) );` 

and I get a nice var_dump :S

Comment: You'll have to var dump it the right context. try var_dump-ing your `$keyword_array` right inside the function to make sure it's not empty. You could also assign your `keyword_query` call to a variable and dump that inside the loop: `$new = keyword_query($keyword_array[$i]) echo "<pre>"; var_dump($new); exit;` do that inside the loop.

Comment: First test dumping `$keyword_array` in the function - WORKS! :D

Second test dumping this: `$new = keyword_query($keyword_array[$i]);
  echo "<pre>"; 
  var_dump($new); 
  exit;`

inside of the of the `for` loop I get this: 

`array (size=1)
  'keyword' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty`

Comment: Found half of the problem. 
$keyword wasn't an array. not it's `$keyword = array();` and it works. 

but I get an error (3 times) on the query line: 

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\PHPExcel\api_fun.php on line 15

Which I don't even understand what that means.

this is the query: `$research_key_query = "https://example.com/api/banana/ajax/kaka?term=$keyword&country=US&auth_token=666";`

@Adelphia

Comment: It's from an array, but still - it is a string :S, so WTH?

Comment: @ElectricWizard `$keyword` is an array, you're trying to put it in a string like it's a string. try `foreach($keyword as $k){ $research_key_query = "https://example.com/api/banana/ajax/kaka?term=$keyword&country=US&auth_token=66‌​6"; /* run your query here */ }`

Comment: or if there's only one value in it, you can do `$research_key_query = "https://example.com/api/banana/ajax/kaka?term={$keyword[0]}&country=US&auth_token=66‌​6";`

Comment: only variable... 

and It doesn't work. (all the query doesn't run) 

I also tried: `'https://example.com/api/banana/ajax/kaka?term=".$keyword[0]."&country=US&auth_tok‌​en=66‌​6';`

Comment: @Adelphia as far as i understood, $keyword should be a sting and not an array since it's getting a string element from the array, 
but then I get back to the point I was before :'(

Comment: Are you urlencoding your keyword?

Comment: No. Should I? :0 What does that mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `global $research_key_array, $keyword;` from the first function to `global $research_key_array;`

Works great now!

Thanks @Adelphia !